# Count multiple items in the same column pulling data from 2 tables - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and I need to count the number of times any role shows up in each movie

Example of Tables:

Movie Table

```
TITLE           MOVIEID     OTHER STUFF....
-------------   -------
MOVIE TITLE 1   ID# 1
MOVIE TITLE 2   ID# 2
MOVIE TITLE 3   ID# 3
ETC...
```

Role Table

```
ROLEID      MOVIEID     OTHER STUFF....
-------     -------
ROLE #1     ID# 1
ROLE #2     ID# 1
ROLE #3     ID# 2
ROLE #4     ID# 2
ROLE #5     ID# 3
ROLE #6     ID# 4
ROLE #7     ID# 5
ROLE #8     ID# 3
ETC....
```

I would like to get an output that looks like this:

```
TITLE           NUMROLES
-------------   --------------------------------------
MOVIE TITLE 1   COUNT (ROLE.MOVIEID) FOR MOVIE TITLE 1
MOVIE TITLE 2   COUNT (ROLE.MOVIEID) FOR MOVIE TITLE 2
MOVIE TITLE 3   COUNT (ROLE.MOVIEID) FOR MOVIE TITLE 3
MOVIE TITLE 4   COUNT (ROLE.MOVIEID) FOR MOVIE TITLE 4
MOVIE TITLE 5   COUNT (ROLE.MOVIEID) FOR MOVIE TITLE 5
ETC...
```

I have tried a several different things but I seem to always get a total count of all the roles instead of them being counted individually.

My "best" output Example:

```
mysql> SELECT TITLE, COUNT(ROLE.MOVIEID) AS NUMROLES
    -> FROM MOVIE, ROLE
    -> GROUP BY TITLE;
+-----------------------------+----------+
| TITLE                       | NUMROLES |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Amadeus                     |      138 |
| Apollo 13                   |      138 |
| Batman                      |      138 |
| Batman & Robin              |      138 |
| Batman Begins               |      138 |
| Batman Forever              |      138 |
| Batman Returns              |      138 |
| Casablanca                  |      138 |
| Dirty Harry                 |      138 |
| Few Good Men, A             |      138 |
| Field of Dreams             |      138 |
| Fly, The                    |      138 |
| Forrest Gump                |      138 |
| Godfather, The              |      138 |
| Gone with the Wind          |      138 |
| Jerry Maguire               |      138 |
| Mrs. Doubtfire              |      138 |
| Naked City, The             |      138 |
| Sixth Sense, The            |      138 |
| Sudden Impact               |      138 |
| Terminator 2:  Judgment Day |      138 |
| Terminator, The             |      138 |
| Tootsie                     |      138 |
| Wizard of Oz, The           |      138 |
+-----------------------------+----------+
24 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I am thinking I don't have the proper knowledge of what I should be using in this case, can anyone point me in the right direction without just giving me the answer??

Bonus:

I also need to filter out any titles that don't have at least 6 for count of (ROLE.MOVIEID) - I am thinking I need to use HAVING for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close, just need to tweak your `JOIN` (it is missing a predicate), and add your `HAVING` for your bonus:

```
SELECT TITLE, COUNT(*) AS NUMROLES
FROM MOVIE M
JOIN ROLE R ON M.MOVIEID = R.MOVIEID --This is the join predicate (condition)
GROUP BY TITLE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;
```

This is explicit `JOIN` syntax.  It's best practice to use this as the implicit variant (ie. commas in your `FROM` clause) is long since depreciated and harder to use anyway.

Note that you can use `COUNT(r.movieID)` if you want, but `COUNT(*)` will count the rows in the same fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was pretty sure I needed to do some sort of join, I tried a leftjoin at some point but I did it incorrectly I think.

Comment: @programmingnovice NP, thanks for including all the detail in your question.  By default a `JOIN` is an `INNER JOIN`, which means your results will be limited to only matches from both tables.  Ex. If there is a movie with no roles, it will not return in the above `JOIN`.  A `LEFT JOIN` will keep all rows from the 'left' table (movies) and will display `NULL` for any values that don't exist in the 'right' table (roles).  In this case you just need the normal `INNER JOIN` or `JOIN`, but if there were movies without roles that you wanted to see, you would need a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @programmingnovice This is a good, simple image of the joins https://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Comment: @programmingnovice Lastly, your join in your question has no predicate or join condition.  That will create a cartesian product, meaning every row from the left table will be joined to every row from the right table.  As Harshil mentioned, this is called a `CROSS JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query:

```
SELECT TITLE, COUNT(ROLE.MOVIEID) AS NUMROLES
FROM MOVIE, ROLE
GROUP BY TITLE;
```

Here, you're doing `Cross Join` between tables `MOVIE` & `ROLE`. Which leads you to wrong result.

What you need here is `Inner Join` of these 2 tables based on the **common column**  `MOVIEID`.

Following query should work:

```
SELECT m.TITLE, COUNT(r.MOVIEID) AS NUMROLES
FROM MOVIE m
inner join ROLE r
on m.MOVIEID = r.MOVIEID
GROUP BY m.TITLE
having NUMROLES >=6;
```

`having NUMROLES >=6` is used to filter out `TITLE` with 5 or less than 5 counts.

You can learn more about `JOIN` by [clicking here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).